# Fit multiple sine waves with linear regression (R)

Tags: r, linear-regression, trigonometry

I'm trying to fit multiple sine waves (three to be precise) to data using the `lm` function in R. I am able to get a result, but it looks far from correct:

[image: Sine wave fit to data]

The green line is kinda wobbly, as it should be, but it seems to be only a single sine (with parabola added), and doesn't match the data very well. What am I doing wrong?

The code I used: (The periods are hardcoded, as they were given to me. Also, `timetopdh` is the time in seconds, `heightdh` the water level at a certain point in time.)

```
plot(timetopdh,heightopdh,xlim=topvector, ylim = c(0,270))

period1 <- 545
period2 <- 205
period3 <- 85

sin11 <- sin(2*pi/period1*timetopdh)
sin12 <- cos(2*pi/period1*timetopdh)

sin21 <- sin(2*pi/period2*timetopdh)
sin22 <- cos(2*pi/period2*timetopdh)

sin31 <- sin(2*pi/period3*timetopdh)
sin32 <- cos(2*pi/period3*timetopdh)

lmsinus <- lm(heightopdh ~ poly(timetopdh,2) + sin11 + sin12 + sin21 + sin22 + sin31 + sin32)

fitted_for_lines <- fitted(lmsinus)
pred <- predict(lmsinus, newdata=data.frame(timetopdh = timetopdh)) 
lines(timetopdh, pred, col=3, lwd=3)
```

Answer (score 1):

That is pretty well matched, it should not follow the data exactly. A linear model is supposed to create the best fit (of a straight line) that it can which reduces the variation in Y as much as it can. The green line does exactly that for you (though not straight)

You have only one line because you asked for only one line. The time and height were plotted point per point against each other in the order of the list they were stored in and passed into plot.

The line was drawn from the prediction using the supplied data, but the points were drawn from those other two sets; `timetopdh,heightopdh`. If you had wanted the sinus waves to print, then you need to ask for each one but name using an appropriate graphing method for them, usually a line graph.

Comment: You're right, I shouldn't expect the fit to be perfect. What I meant, however, is that it seems as though the regression only takes into account one of the three sine waves, as the green line looks very similar to the standard sine wave.

Could you elaborate on what you mean with your last sentence ("you need to ask for each one but name ...")?

Comment: I do not see where you entered the actual sin variables in to be plotted, just the single set of height and time data. (I can't see the data to know what is in those files). If you want R to plot the sinwaves of three of those calculations, then expressly push the into `plot(sin31) and add however many you wish as well as the prediction line.

Comment: If those files have all the points, then the waves overlap in some way and having a scatter plot is hiding the individual movements. If you pull out the points from each wave path, and plot them as lines. Where the differ from each other and the AB line will become more obvious than with the raw points---connected points tell more of a story.